# Exporting a sub site from sharepoint 2010 to sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration

On doing the Import-SPWeb command I am getting this error:

```
FatalError: The required attribute 'FeatureDefinitionScope' is missing.
```

Please point me to the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their is no direct way(OOTB) to export a site from 2010 and import into 2013. But with little effort you can do it. their are couple of ways.

1. Use 3rd party tool i.e metlogix or sharegate etc( most of the 3rd party tools offer free trial).
2. Use Content Database approach, take the backup of CDB, move to 2013 farm and attach & mount.
3. If you want to spend some time then try the manual way. In this way, you have to manually update the version number inside the export package. Follow the instruction from this blog.

[How to move a List from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013](http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/08/how-to-move-a-list-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013.html)

Comment: This is helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can't use export and import, as this will not work across versions.  Your path to 2013 should be attaching your wss3.0 db to 2010, so that it can upgrade, and then detach and attach it to 2013.  Backup/Restore does NOT work across versions... even 2010 to 2013...

For more information, click [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f76c4c12-8919-40b1-a8d1-be6ef72bb399/migrate-a-subsite-from-sharepoint-2010-to-2013).